# R issue when trying to get heat map. Error: bandwidths must be strictly positive

Tags: r, heatmap, spss, variance

I have been given data in SPSS these 5 variable. I try to use this DB to sketch a heat map but i get the "Error: bandwidths must be strictly positive".

```
Brand XP Contact Impression Memorability
1   4   1   100 14
1   4   1   100 0
1   4   1   100 0    
1   4   1   99  97
1   4   1   100 60
1   4   1   100 0
1   4   1   100 100
1   4   1   100 60
1   4   1   73  75
1   4   1   100 67
1   4   1   99  1
1   4   1   100 0
1   4   1   100 0
1   4   1   100 7
1   4   1   100 0
1   4   1   74  33
```

I import the data with:

```
Heatmap.data = as.data.set(spss.system.file('database.sav'))
```

And have this code because I sketch many heat maps, but the problem is with the heatmap with XP = 4.

```
for (i in 1: n.brands) {

createMap <- function(map, colorMap, colorContour, beginGradX, beginGradY, endGradX, endGradY, mapTitle)
{
  image(map, col = colorMap, axes = FALSE)
  contour(map, add = TRUE, col = colorContour, drawlabels = FALSE)
  axis(1, at = seq(beginGradX, endGradX, by=1))
  axis(2, at = seq(beginGradY, endGradY, by=1))
  box()
  title(mapTitle)
}

Heatmap.data.sub=Heatmap.data[Heatmap.data$brand == i,]
X = na.omit(Heatmap.data.sub$impression)/100
Y = na.omit(Heatmap.data.sub$memorability)/100
```

This is where I get the error (in this line):

```
smoothedMatrix = kde2d(X, Y, n = 500, lims = c(range(X), range(Y)))
```

I have been searching the net and stackoverflow and people say, that the problem is that the variance is 0. But in my case variance is not 0 but variance of Impression = 137 and variance on Memorability = 1190.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just to be sure,  could you please check the output of `range(X)` and `range(Y)`  ?

Comment: `range(X)` is from 0.3 to 1.00 `range(Y)` from 0 to 1. `var(X) = 0.0137` and `var(Y) = 0.1189`.